# Facing problem in running a php website in docker container

Tags: php, docker, apache

Can anyone help me. I have a project. My project directory looks like this
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yg33S.png)
It is a PHP project. I want to run it into docker container. My **docker-compose.yml** code is given below:

```
version: "3"
services:
  academic-lms:
    container_name: academic-lms-container
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - my-volume:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 8004:80

volumes:
  my-volume:
```

And my Dockerfiles' code is:

```
FROM php:8.0-apache
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN service apache2 restart

WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY ./src .

RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/application/config/database.php
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/application/config/routes.php
```

The website loads but this error occured.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7Gr5.png)
I did not find any solution. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Can anyone verify if the docker-compose and Dockerfile code is perfect or not?

Comment: "*Can anyone verify if the [...] Dockerfile code is perfect or not?*" - [It is not (`docs.docker.com`)](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#run).

Comment: is this path `/var/www/html/application/config/database.php` valid? aren't you missing a `src/` there?

Comment: Yes, this one is valid. I have copied all the src files to the /var/www/html folder. And then I need to change the permission for this file.

Comment: `chmod 777` is almost always a security error.  The `volumes:` mount in your Compose setup will also cause problems where changes in your Dockerfile get ignored.  You also don't need to `RUN service ...`, at best it does nothing.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Just mounting the files solved the issue. Thanks all.